# Hibernate envers customs table

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers

I am migrating a old project to a new tech stack without changing the database model(I  know that is bad but no option). So I already have a audit table defined which has data as well.

Can I use the same audit table with Hibernate envers audit framework?

For other CRUD operations I am using spring data JPA.
what would be the  best option for auditing? I want to audit delete as well.

Comment: is your existing audit tables are also created by envers?

Comment: No. It is a normal table with few column.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use existing audit tables as Audit tables created by envers have a specific format. If your existing audit tables follow the same pattern then you can use envers annotations to map table name and column names of your audit tables to envers tables.

You can refer [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/#tables) for more info.